# How do I initialize a new python object with existing object and a new parameter value in python?

Tags: python, oop

Here is my code snippet:-

```
class Board:
    def __init__(self,level):
        self.lvl=level
        self.val=0
class State:
    def __init__(self):
        self.p=Board(0)
        self.p.val=100
        self.u=self.p
```

I want that u has a level of 1 and val of 100. I know i can modify separately, but i want to pass reference of p while initializing u and a level value 1.
Something like self.u=Board(1) would not solve my purpose.

Comment: Make `Board` accept `val` as a second parameter…?! `self.u = Board(1, 100)`…?!

Comment: That's right but i want to pass reference of p to u so that u.val=p.val.

Comment: Well then… `self.p = self.u = Board(0, 100)`…?! But why have two references to the same object in the first place?

Comment: It's not clear whether you want `u.val` and `p.val` to have the same initial value but change independantly or if what you're asking for is that whenever `p.val` changes `u.val` changes accordingly...

Comment: `self.p = self.u = Board(0, 100)` This would actually go wrong if I am using a list or any other structure with recursion. Simply, the state of u has to be same as p with a level of +1.

Comment: Then don't bother with creating two `Board` objects, create a method or `@property` on `State` that returns `self.p.lvl + 1`…!? `@property def u(self): return Board(self.p.lvl + 1)`

Answer (score 1):

After many tries I thought copy constructor can be used. But I think if reference passing or any easy method exists It would be efficient.

```
class Board:
    def __init__(self,level,orig=None):
        if orig is None:
            self.val=0
        else:
            self.val=orig.val
        self.lvl=level
class State:
    def __init__(self):
        self.p=Board(0)
        self.p.val=100
        self.u=Board(1,self.p)
```